# How to install tflearn module on anaconda distribution in windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, tflearn

I have already install most of the libraries on anaconda. In one of my code is showing that No module named 'tflearn'.

I also used the command conda install tflearn.
it shows the failed message.

```
   PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from 
   current channels:
```

- tflearn

Current channels:

- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch

  what should i do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For python2

```
sudo pip install tflearn
```

For python3

```
sudo pip3 install tflearn
```

Comment: 'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file in Windows. How could the OP mark this as an accepted answer?

Answer (score 4):

I found a simple approach for Anaconda.

Go here (https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn) to make a clone of the tflean repository or download a copy in a zip form. Extract the files in the zip file.

Launch the anaconda prompt and navigate to the folder that contains the extracted downloaded files.

Then run:

python setup.py install

You can find my source from here (http://tflearn.org/installation/)

I hope this helps.

Comment: It really helps.  I have set up tflearn inside a Anaconda Docker container. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

open your anaconda terminal and run:

```
conda install -c derickl tflearn
```

Comment: While that may solve the problem, it will reflect much more positively on your answer if you could at least say a few words why that channel.

Comment: PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: - tflearn

Comment: `-c` is basically to used to specify the channel/package owner to install the package from. You can use https://anaconda.org/search?q=tflearn to find in which all channels/package owners own tflearn. Make sure you choose the right platform.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that on the anaconda [website](https://anaconda.org/derickl/tflearn) tflearn is only listed as an OSX package, so you can either download the [source](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn.git) and install that manually

Or you could do

```
pip install tflearn
```

Also, make sure you got `tensorflow` installed

Comment: i tried the command conda install -c derickl tflearn,not woking ,again showing same error and channels showing@FlyingTeller

Comment: @manishkumar seems like I overlooked that in the anaconda channels tflearn is only for OSX

Comment: i tried pip also.Collecting tflearn
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Manish\Anaconda3\lib\site-
TypeError: parse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transport_encoding'
@FlyingTeller

Comment: And what do you get using pip?

Comment: File "C:\Users\Manish\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)

Comment: i got this type of lines.  File "C:\Users\Manish\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 731, in __init__
    namespaceHTMLElements=False,
TypeError: parse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transport_encoding@FlyingTeller

Comment: try updating your pip `conda install pip` or html5lib, which sometimes causes problems `conda install -c anaconda html5lib`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
conda install -c bjrn tflearn
```

It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't use a regular anaconda install, i had the same issue you had so this worked for me:

> pip install tflearn

Answer (score 0):

## Anaconda install in Windows 10

I installed it just by typing

```
pip install tflearn

Collecting tflearn
   Downloading tflearn-0.5.0.tar.gz (107 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy
Requirement already satisfied: six 
Collecting Pillow
   Downloading Pillow-8.0.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (2.1 MB)
Successfully built tflearn
Installing collected packages: Pillow, tflearn
Successfully installed Pillow-8.0.1 tflearn-0.5.0
```