# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tflearn' problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

I have installed 'tflearn' in my conda environment and when i try to use it it shows an error saying "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tflearn'" i saw already some threads about this but none of them seem to work.

Comment: Please tell the command you used to install tflearn

Comment: first i activated the environment via
activate myEnv
pip install tflearn

Comment: probably this can help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48821174/how-to-install-tflearn-module-on-anaconda-distribution-in-windows-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
conda install pillow
```

then

```
pip install -U --no-deps tflearn
```

Comment: tried both,and they both show the same error

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
- tflearn

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: im using windows 7

Comment: When you installed it for the first time, if it was installed but not imported, try to copy all the files inside the **tflearn-master** folder at the following location: 
**C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages**

Comment: now shows a problem with numpy oh my god , thanks for that solve btw helped

Comment: Glad could help.